# Visa to France got cancelled twice for a 2yrs old baby

Tags: indian-citizens, children, schengen-visas

I have an Indian friend whose wife is coming to do her management studies in France. They have a baby daughter of 2yrs.
Now the problem is that they have the valid passport for the baby daughter, however, when they applied for her visa, it got cancelled (for first time) and then they tried tourism (didn't work either, second time cancelled).
I wanted to help them but I have no idea how to help them. Is there a way to get the baby with her mother?
Whom to contact in this regard? Any help will be highly appreciable.

Comment: By cancelled, do you mean that the visa was not issued, or that the baby was not admitted at the border? If the former, were any reasons given (please include a picture of the notice, redact any identifying information)?

Comment: I do not understand how to reconcile the rest of this question with the statement "they have the valid visa for the baby daughter."

Comment: Reapplying for tourism is visa fraud.

Comment: I don't understand the question at all. You say they have a visa, but then you say they applied for a visa, and then you say it was cancelled. If you can tell us exactly what they have, what they applied for, and what response they received from the consulate to their applications, that would be a good start.

Comment: regroupement familial ? https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F11166

Comment: Maybe this question should be moved to expatriates.stackexchange ?

Comment: "tried tourism" doesnt seem a smart strategy to me

Comment: @phoog The question was edited wrongly(without my consent). Please check it now.

Comment: @ZachLipton The question was edited wrongly(without my consent). Please check it now

Comment: @Shamina Thanks. That helps, but some parts of this are still unclear. They never had a visa for the child, right? What reason was given for the refusals? Why did they apply for a tourist visa when the intent was not to come for tourism?

Comment: What was wrong with the edit? The rollback makes it worse again. What is a visa cancellation when the visa was never issued?

Comment: I rolled back to the first revision because each revision made this more confusing. Not that the original made any sense. We need OP to reword this completely. Also, randomly asking for visas will never lead anywhere.

Comment: @HankyPanky It is my very poor writing skills. Sorry for that. My ignorance

Comment: @Shamina When a visa is 'cancelled' it means you had a visa, and then it was taken away. If you asked for a visa and they said "no", the word for that is "refused".

Answer (score 6):

> **I wanted to help them but I have no idea how to help them**

1. Find out the reasons for the refusals. They will very likely have been given specific reasons. If they have the refusal on paper you can publish it in a question on this website after redacting (blacking out) the personal information.
2. Encourage them not to try randomly choosing types of visa in the hope they'll get lucky. To the officials that just looks like deliberate deception. It is the sort of behaviour that can lead to very detrimental consequences.